# Column types problems in Pandas-profiling

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm Using pandas-profiling in a dataset that contains 140 columns.

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_parquet("ConsultationForm.parquet", columns= sorted(columnNames),engine="pyarrow")
df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
df.head()
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report", explorative=True, minimal=True)
profile.to_file('ConsultationForm_profiling3.html')
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() argument after * must be an iterable, not bool
```

How Could I Fix it?

Thanks

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: The last one line

Comment: Look into ProfileReport then.

Comment: What version of pandas profiling are you using? My first guess is that this is a bug in that library.